# Cycles - rendered viewport really slow in Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

So since months I am experiencing that cycles is getting slower and slower for me
in Blender 2.8 and I thought with the release coming it might become better.

However when I have a very simple scene and use cycles to have preview it takes several seconds just to update small position adjustments i make to a sun lamp for example.

I do not know if I am having a setting wrong so it would be really nice if someone could help me.

I use a GTX 1070 as GPU and have enabled it.
Tile size is 240x256 (autotile)
viewport tile: I tried 64, 128, 256, 512.
CPU is i7 6700K and 16GB DDR4 2800Mhz.

Comment: I'm not sure how simple your simple scene is. Cycles isn't really meant for real-time rendering/preview, that's what Eevee is for. Although Cycles needs time to render the samples in preview I haven't experiences it becoming slower over the course of the development. It does become slower with growing scene complexity.

Comment: Well, yes you are right that it is not meant for a real time rendering / preview, however it was always able to show me complex scenes  in 2.79 and i could adjust lights etc. 

As for the scene, My profile picture is the scene ^^, really just 3 lowpoly buildings and really no difficult materials.

Comment: That should work fine. Can't give you a definitive answer, but I can suggest the following: The first thing I would check is that your GPU is selected as CUDA device in `Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices > CUDA` to rule out that it uses integrated graphics. Then I'd update the graphics driver: https://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx?lang=en

Comment: "*takes several seconds just to update small position adjustments*" Small or big, adjustments require recalculating and re-uploading the scene, there are no optimizations here as far as I know, so regardless of how small the change is it will re-render everything

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replys guys!
Yes the GPU is set as cuda and it is using the 1070.

Sorry i dont know how to quote,

Before it was not like that. I could handle heavy glass shaders, the engine
started of course to render unless i moved something so it had to start again but now it takes several seconds maybe up to 25 seconds till it even starts doing that. Before it was immediate. I think I should capture what I mean and upload it right? Maybe it would be easier to understand what I mean.

Comment: 10-15* seconds not 25.

Comment: try to run blender from command line with `--factory-startup` option
for example: `"c:\blender\blender.exe --factory-startup"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use combined GPU AND CPU for rendering. Using square tiles will increase render speed (any square numbers "X²" for better performance). You can find some sites to help you minimizing the render time.